# What compiler argument shall be provided to gcc for it to think it is g++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Is it possible to write an argument to gcc such that it would think its G++?

Comment: Isn't already gcc detecting the file extension and launching the appropriate tool ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) states there is a flag `-x` to specify the language:

```
gcc -x c++ ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Why would you want to do this? As far as I know, the only difference is that `g++` in addition passes `-lstdc++` to the linker, to link the C++ Standard library.

So if you pass that option to GCC, it should forward it to the linker, and all should be fine. But I really don't see a reason in doing this. Just use `g++`.

That said, I used `gcc` myself in the past, to compile C++ code. When I had a bunch of files, mixed C++ and C code, I just compiled everything using `gcc`, because `g++` by default treats `.c` as being C++ code, which breaks the build when the C code uses such things as `new` as identifiers. Adding `-lstdc++` always worked nicely.

See the GCC manpage

> **Compiling C++ Programs**
>
> C++ source files conventionally use one of the suffixes .C, .cc, .cpp, .CPP, .c++, .cp, or .cxx; C++ header files often use .hh, .hpp, .H,
>          or (for shared template code) .tcc; and preprocessed C++ files use the suffix .ii.  GCC recognizes files with these names and compiles them
>          as C++ programs even if you call the compiler the same way as for compiling C programs (usually with the name gcc).
>
> However, the use of gcc does not add the C++ library.  g++ is a program that calls GCC and treats .c, .h and .i files as C++ source files
>          instead of C source files unless -x is used, and automatically specifies linking against the C++ library.  This program is also useful when
>          precompiling a C header file with a .h extension for use in C++ compilations.  On many systems, g++ is also installed with the name c++.
>
> When you compile C++ programs, you may specify many of the same command-line options that you use for compiling programs in any language;
>          or command-line options meaningful for C and related languages; or options that are meaningful only for C++ programs.

Comment: `g++` also specifies `-lm`, which may cause problems if your build system is designed to detect and complain about unnecessary shared-library dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

'gcc' is 'Gnu Compiler Collection'. If you pass it a C++ file, it invokes the C++ compiler, 'g++'.

Despite this, 'gcc' and 'g++' not interchangeable for c++ files. gcc runs g++ with a few additional arguments that I can't remember off the top of my head.

When you compile c++ files, I would always use g++